# How to interpret the strange training curve for RNN?

Tags: tensorflow

I use the `tensorflow` to train a simple two-layer RNN on my data set. The training curve is shown as follows:

[image: RNN curve]

where, the `x-axis` is the steps(in one step, a `batch_size` number of samples is used to update the net parameters), the `y-axis` is the accuracy. The red, green, blue line is the accuracy in training set, validation set, and the test set, respectively. It seems the training curve is not smooth and have some corrupt change. Is it reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried gradient clipping, Adam optimizer and learning rate decay?
From my experience, gradient clipping can prevent exploding gradients, Adam optimizer can converge faster, and learning rate decay can improve generalization.

Have you shuffled the training data?

In addition, visualizing the distribution of weights also helps debugging the model.

Comment: Hi, Dear Xiang, thank you very much for your valuable suggestions and experience! Currently I just use the SGD optimizer and adjust the learning rate, the other parameters are set as default and fixed. I'll investigate the performance as you suggested later. Yes, I've shuffled the training data after an epoch done.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely OK since you are using SGD. General trend is that your accuracy increases as number of used minibatches increases, however, some minibatches could significantly 'differ' from most of the others, therefore accuracy could be poor on them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! In this experiments, I just set a fixed batch_size, say 30. And I'm trying to experiment with variable learning rates. Initial experiments show that the learning rate is too large in the above experiments. I'll try to experiment with variable batch_sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your test and validation accuracy drops horribly at times 13 and 21 is suspicious. E.g. 13 drops the test score below epoch 1.

This implies your learning rate is probably too large: a single mini-batch shouldn't cause that amount of weight change.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Yes, I tried variable learning rates, it shows the learning rate in the above experiments is too large. If the learning rate is set to a relatively small value, the curve seems to be smoother, but with slow convergence. So it needs more steps. In addition, the step in my experiment doesn't mean the `epoch` as you said. The `x-axis` in the above figure should have a multiplier factor of 1000. (sorry that I didn't indicate it in the question). I have `1600` training samples, and batch_size=30, so one epoch is about more than 50 steps.